# Wrong salutation (Ms instead of Mr) in international air ticket

Tags: tickets

My son's Kuwait Airways ticket from India to Italy has the wrong title: 'Ms' instead of 'Mr'. Contacting the airline, they have included a remark in their system to read 'Ms' as 'Mr'. However, as the ticket/boarding pass will still mention 'Ms', will this be an issue at the immigration counter at the airport?

Comment: What's the first name? Ms John Smith is an obvious mistake. Ms Sam Smith could be a man using a woman's ticket.

Comment: Sons name is Sahil Ray

Comment: Seems to be an exclusive masculine name, so at least in India everyone will be 99.99% sure that "Ms" is a mistake.

Comment: Relevant topic https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79701/how-to-book-a-flight-if-my-passport-doesnt-state-my-gender

Comment: ... and then there's the possibility that someone identifies neither as MR nor MS or that the fact changes between booking and flying (though the latter case is typically also accompanied by a change of one's given name)

Answer (score 30):

> they have included a remark in their system to read 'Ms' as 'Mr'.

**That's it then, don't worry.** And checking for titles on a ticket is not the job of an immigration officer, it is the job of check-in staff and  they will see a note by their office.

Many airlines do not allow any changes to names after a ticket has been issued but if you request them for such changes due to a mistake they indicate those in remarks for check-in staff. That's exactly what they did for you and that's good enough, don't worry.

I have made this mistake multiple times wih different airlines and those *remarks* have always helped. I've never been questioned about those.

Comment: "Checking <strike>for titles on </strike>a ticket is not the job of an immigration officer" - they don't look at the ticket *at all*.

Comment: @MartinBonner Are you sure?  I imagine an immigration officer might ask to see a return ticket?

Comment: @gerrit: I've never been asked to show one on entry to the USA. (I've only ever flown to Italy as an EU citizen).

Comment: @MartinBonner Me neither — but I can imagine they might look at it if they are suspicious and take someone in for extra questioning.

Comment: Thanks. I was worried about how the immigration people may view the issue.

Comment: I managed to get an email from the ticketing agency with a screenshot showing the remarks to read 'Ms' as 'Mr' (KU PLEASE READ PAX 3 NAME AS RAY/SAHILMR). Hope this will suffice, in case they have any queries.

Comment: Easy to see why it happens to you!  Is "Hanky" Mr or Ms?  Hard to tell!

Comment: @MartinBonner I've had some countries want to see my ticket. For example, it's required to use the visa-free transit option in China. I wouldn't be surprised if the U.S. or an E.U. country asked under certain circumstances (e.g. if what they had seen already hadn't sufficiently established in their mind that the person entering did not intend to overstay.)

Comment: @davidbak haha good one!

Comment: @davidbak It’s clearly a pet form of _Henry_, so male. Then again, Panky is equally clearly a pet form of _Penelope_, so we’re back to square one.

Answer (score 5):

There is no issue with this on immigration counter as titles are optional everywhere.

You would note that your son's passport doesn't have a title or salutation, that should tell you how important it is to get this right.

I would be more worried about the transit through Kuwait. The airport is undergoing construction so I hope your son is able to find seating as the airport gets very crowded. A new temporary terminal and a new airport are both under construction.

Relax, and have a safe trip.

Comment: "Titles are optional everywhere"  Someone needs to tell that to thousands of programmers writing Javascript to make sure you don't leave that blank on the web form.

Answer (score 3):

From personal experience, this absolutely didn't matter for me, when some airline a while ago (can't remember which one now, possibly Emirates or Egypt Air) issued a ticket to me with "Mrs" on it instead of "Mr".  I contacted them at the time and they told me not to worry.

When I arrived at the airport, nobody even remotely bothered to check the title/salutation. The name match fully against my passport - and that was sufficient.

When you arrive at the passport or customs control, you don't need your boarding pass nor ticket, so this shouldn't matter again.

Answer (score 1):

No problem. My wife travelled once on a " Mr" salutation. To Kuwait on a Kuwait airways flight from Cochin airport.